# Name of entire group of four C++ declaration symbols?

Tags: c++, syntax

My understanding is that generically the entire group of non-alphanumeric characters like *, ?, ;, #, etc. can be called punctuators.  However, in an expression like

```
    3*4
```

the * is specifically known as an "operator" whereas in a declaration like

```
    int *p;
```

the * is not an operator but instead merely indicates that p is a pointer.  Similarly the 3 additional symbols &, [], and () are not called operators when used in declarations.  I know what all of these symbols mean in their various contexts, how they are pronounced, and what they do, but is there a specific name for this entire group of four symbols when used in declarations?  I've always called them "attributes" for lack of anything better and I can't find anything specific in the language standards regarding a name for the group.

Comment: There isn't any name in the C Standard nor any common name that I know of; I normally call them "symbols in declarations"

Comment: why do you need to call them? I've never seen a need to do that. Simply call brackets, ampersand or parentheses is enough. Moreover, they're still operators and be affected by **operator precedence**, otherwise how will you parse `int a[SIZE*3+(B/2 - 1)] = {0};`?

Comment: The official term is "squigglies".

Comment: To clarify, you mean *only* in the context of type declaration, right? So not `;`, and `&` only counts in C++ when used to mean a reference, and not at all in C? In that case I'm not aware of any particular term, other than "punctuation used in type names".

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc In the declaration you list, `*` is an operator but `[]` is not.  The language grammar for declarators determines how declarators are parsed. There is no "precedence" of symbols in declarators

Answer (score 4):

As you already know that the characters like *, ?, ;, # etc. are known as [Punctuator](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/punctuators.htm) in C and C++.

> A punctuator is a token that has syntactic and semantic meaning to the
>   compiler, **but the exact significance depends on the context.** A
>   punctuator can also be a token that is used in the syntax of the
>   preprocessor.

**Punctuators are not operators or identifiers.** Some characters can be used either as a punctuator or as an operator, or as part of an operator. **The context of the occurrence specifies the meaning.**

From [C Standard#6.4.6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.6):

> A punctuator is a symbol that has independent syntactic and semantic significance. **Depending on context, it may specify an operation to be performed** (which in turn may yield a value or a function designator, produce a side effect, or some combination thereof) in which case it is known as an operator (other forms of operator also exist in some contexts). An operand is an entity on which an operator acts.

Their meaning is different based on the context in which they have been used. So, there is no specific name for the entire group of four symbols and if you want to call them with a single word then, I believe, the word **punctuator** is the most appropriate word.

Additional : Most of the punctuator are common in C and C++.
**But C++ is having some additional punctuators like** `::`, `.*`, `new`, `delete` etc.

Comment: I think that's a more general term than the OP is asking about. I believe the question is specifically about the group of punctuators used in type names.

Comment: In the question OP is asking --> "non-alphanumeric characters like *, ?, ;, #, etc.". Here `*`is an operator, `;` does not come under operator but represent statement terminator, `#` is a preprocessor directive etc. So, they all have different meaning but they all are - Punctuator.

Comment: The entire sentence in question is "My understanding is that generically the entire group of non-alphanumeric characters like *, ?, ;, #, etc. can be called punctuators", which says the OP already knows the word punctuators. The rest of the question mentions operators as a subset of punctuators, and asks what the word for a different subset is.

Comment: @DanielH: Yes I agree, OP already knows about punctuators. In my answer, I am saying that - "The context of the occurrence specifies the meaning." There is no as such a single word for that specific group and if you want to call them with the single word then the word **punctuators** is most appropriate word.

Answer (score 3):

> but is there a specific name for this entire group of four symbols when used in declarations?

Sort of. The grammatical construct that references these symbols in declarations are "declarators". This name isn't really used outside of standard discussions however; there just isn't much need to refer to declarator symbols as a group.

Also, there are more declarator symbols than that. [In C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/declarations), there is `()` (for function declarations). [C++ gives us](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations) `...` (parameter pack declarations), and `&&` (r-value reference).

Answer (score 0):

When used in a statement declaration those 4 symbols are considered declarator modifiers. The classifier punctuator simply represents that they can be used in more than one context, therefore they are also considered punctuators. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267831(v=vs.60).aspx

When used in a non-declarative manor: all 4 of those symbols (*, &, [], ()) are all considered operators in c++. There are different types of operators such as arithmetic operators, relational operators, and logical operators. The multiplication symbol belongs to the arithmetic operators category where as the other 4 operators belong to the misc/other category of operators. * is called a deference operator. & is called an address-of operator. [] is called a subscript operator. () is called a function call operator. Since they are all considered operators in c++ this means that you can override their functionality.

This is a good link that demonstrates the operator precedence in c++: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operators-c-c/

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking about the symbols as operators, but rather their name when used in declarations:  *but is there a specific name for this entire group of four symbols when used in declarations?*

Comment: The `*` in `int i = *p` is the dereference operator, but the `*` in `int *p = &i`; is not an operator at all, and that one's what the OP's asking about.

Comment: Based upon all of the postings and comments it appears that in the absence of a formal name for the group of symbols a reasonable name would be "declarator modifiers", or maybe just "declaration symbols" to keep it simple. I'm merely looking for a term that's short and sweet and does not step on the toes of some other official term. Of course, these same symbols are also used in typecasts but the term "declaration symbols" still sounds pretty good to me.